# Prove: $(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)=2\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove: $(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)=2\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)\right)$

$|(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)|=8$

Using Moivre's theorem on the LHS:

$$\sqrt{(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)}=2\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{\phi+2k\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\phi+2k\pi}{2}\right),k=0,1$$

This is not correct (checked for $\phi=\pi/3$).

How to prove this equation?

Comment: The statement $(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)=8$ is clearly false.

Comment: The statement is still false, you are missing a square.

Comment: @copper.hat Is the Moivre's theorem the right approach for this proof?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with the $k$ above. Look at Math's answer below. The key to that answer is the fact that ${7 \pi \over 12} = {\pi \over 3} + {\pi \over 4}$.

Comment: What is $\sqrt{z}$ when, like here, $z$ is a complex number which is not positive real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(1+i\sqrt{3})=2(\cos \frac{\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{3}),$$
$$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}).$$ Then the product of these is   $2\sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{7\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{12})$. So    $$2\sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{7\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{12})(\cos {\phi}+i\sin{\phi})=2\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\phi\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since you can write
$(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)e^{i \phi}=2\sqrt{2}e^{i \phi} e^{i {7 \pi \over 12}}$, so
you can concentrate on showing
$(1+i\sqrt{3})(1+i)=2\sqrt{2} e^{i {7 \pi \over 12}}$ instead.